# In which thread is the terminate handler called?

Tags: c++, terminate, terminate-handler

In which thread is called the terminate handler:

1. when an exception is thrown inside a `noexcept` function?
2. when the user call `std::terminate`()?
3. at start up or destruction of `thread`?

Is it defined in the standard, will I have access to `thread_local` objects?

Comment: My common sense tells me it will be called on the thread which called `std::terminate`? I do believe the Standard doesn't address this explicitly.

Comment: I believe it is unspecified behavior (or might be undefined?)

Comment: I'd say on the thread that actually set up the handler, though idk

Comment: I can't imagine there being some mechanism to interrupt whatever some other thread might be doing to get it to run `std::terminate`. I would think the thread calling `std::terminate` gets to run it.

Comment: Making code run on a specific other thread is highly untrivial.  So it just doesn't, it runs on whatever thread suffered the heart-attack.  Easy to try for yourself, makes you feel better about it.

Comment: Thanks, you have conviced me.

Comment: I just checked in the online compiler, the threads that terminates is the one that calls std::terminate.

Answer (score 3):

This answer sum up answers given in comments and an answer now deleted:

- It is not specified in the standard (*DeiDei*, I have checked too in N4618)
- Nevertheless, for technical reasons it is unlikely that the handler is called in an other thread that the one who caused the call to `std::terminate` (*Galik*,*Hans Passant*)
- it has been verified on online compiler (*Rinat Veliakhmedov*), the terminate handler is called in the thread that causes terminate to be called.

You can test it yourself with this code from a deleted answer:

```
#include <string>
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>

std::mutex mutex;
const auto& id = std::this_thread::get_id;
const auto print = [](std::string t){
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
    std::cout << id() << " " << t << std::endl;
};

void my_terminate_handler(){
    print("terminate");
    std::abort();
}

void throwNoThrow() noexcept { throw std::exception(); }
void terminator()            { std::terminate();       }

int main() {
    std::set_terminate(my_terminate_handler);
    print("main");    
#ifdef  CASE1
    auto x1 = std::thread(throwNoThrow);
#elif CASE2
    auto x1 = std::thread(terminator);
#elif CASE3    
    auto x1 = std::thread(throwNoThrow);
#endif
    x1.join();
}
```

**Conclusion** It is unspecified but it seems that the handler is always be called in the thread that causes `std::terminate` to be called. (tested on *gcc-5.4, gcc-7.1, clang-3.8 with pthreads*)